# Python regex with unicode characters bug?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, match, character-properties

Long story short:

```
>>> re.compile(r"\w*").match(u"Français")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1004246b0>
>>> re.compile(r"^\w*$").match(u"Français")
>>> re.compile(r"^\w*$").match(u"Franais")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100424780>
>>>
```

Why doesn't it match the string with unicode characters with `^` and `$` in the regex? As far as I understand `^` stands for the beginning of the string(line) and `$` - for the end of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the [`UNICODE` flag](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.UNICODE), otherwise `\w` is just equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which does not include the character '`ç`'.

```
>>> re.compile(r"^\w*$", re.U).match(u"Fran\xe7ais")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x101474168>
```

Comment: Why does this wort then: `>>> re.compile(r"\w*").match(u"Français")`?

Comment: @ak: Are you sure the match returns `Français` instead of `Fran` with it? Note that without the `$` the regex won't match until the end.

Comment: `\w*` will match absolutely anything. `*` matches 0 or more times.